# put the response of a service inside of a string variable with typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, service, ngfor

i'm working on an angular 4 project and i made a service to get a json from a url, the service.ts looks like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http , Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class EventsService{

    constructor(private http:Http){

    }


    private url: string =  "http://urlofmyjson/events";

    getEvents() {
        return (
            this.http.get(this.url).map((response: Response) => response.json())
        )
    }

}
```

the content of that json looks like this:

```
{
  "events":[
    {
      "title":"event1"
      "location":"location1"
      "date":"date1"
    },
    {
      "title":"event2"
      "location":"location2"
      "date":"date2"
    },
    {
      "title":"event3"
      "location":"location3"
      "date":"date3"
    },
  ]
}
```

and in my component i have this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {EventsService} from './conciertos.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-events',
    templateUrl: './events.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./events.component.scss']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private EventsService: ConciertosService) { }

    events = []:

    ngOnInit() {
        this.EventsService.getEvents().subscribe(   ResponseEvents => this.events=ResponseEvents);

    }

}
```

and then i want to iterate each event of the json with an *ngFor, but as the json retrieves an object with an array inside of it that contains the events objects, i can't iterate it because it throws an error.

how can i put the response of the service inside a string type variable to call and iterate it with *ngFor?

Comment: You simply need to store the array in your `events` property. `this.events = ResponseEvents.events`. Now angular can iterate over the `events` property because it is an array

Comment: What do you mean "put it in a string variable"? You can't iterate a string...

Comment: @LLai that works perfectly, i didn't figure it out that i had to access the string through the Response that way